# How to use predefined routes in ServiceStack with URI instead of query string?

Tags: c#, routes, servicestack

Is it possible  (if yes, how) in ServiceStack to use predefined routes with parameters in the URI?
I can do one or the other but combining both does not seem to work:

```
[Route("/hello/{Name}")]

// ok
1. /hello/myname
2. /json/reply/hello
3. /json/reply/hello?Name=myname

// not ok
4. /json/reply/hello/myname
"The operation 'myname' does not exist for this service"
```

Tried these but none worked:

```
[Route("/*/hello/{Name}")]
[Route("/{*}/hello/{Name}")]
```

In particular, why does 3 work, but not 4?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [ServiceStack's pre-defined routes](http://docs.servicestack.net/routing#pre-defined-routes) are **not customizable** and follow the explicit format:

```
/{format}/[reply|oneway]/{servicename}
```

i.e. you can define your own Custom routes, but you can't change the pre-defined routes which maintains its pre-defined behavior.

To send parameters on the URL you need to use the queryString, e.g:

```
 /json/reply/Hello?name=myname
```

Otherwise you can send parameters using other methods that ServiceStack supports, e.g. serialized Request Body, FormData, HTTP Headers, etc.